# Chrome getting crashed randomly even after chromedriver

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, crash, webdriver

I have a Selenium automation script which was working fine with Chrome v.58, but after the upgrade, my test cases keeps on failing randomly due to the issue `chrome not reachable`.

I have checked the `chromedriver` log file and found out the request to init is failing. Can someone please help me out to solve this.

> [1.961][INFO]: Launching chrome: "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
>   --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-infobars --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-automation --enable-logging --enable-precise-memory-info --ignore-certificate-errors --js-flags=--expose-gc --load-component-extension="C:\Users\prateek.rajendra\AppData\Local\Temp\Mxt94\tmp\scoped_dir10588_12332\internal"
>   --log-level=0 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12666 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --start-maximized --test-type --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir="C:\Users\prateek.rajendra\AppData\Local\Temp\Mxt94\tmp\scoped_dir10588_26250"
>   data: [58.967][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed [59.028][DEBUG]:
>   DevTools request: http://localhost:12666/json/version

Comment: [2.046][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12420/json/version
[4.082][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[4.143][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12420/json/version
[4.347][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[4.408][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12420/json/version
[6.156][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed

Comment: are you sure chromedriver.exe itself is the latest version?

Comment: yes the chromedriver is the latest one, I had posted a issue in in chromedriver support forum, they are suspecting this is due to system load

Answer (score 0):

This is a common got you in the Selenium world. You need to update your chromedriver also and your issue will get fixed.

If I understand correctly currently you have updated the chrome browser but have not update chromedirver. Just go to Selenium website and download the latest driver and your issue will vaporise.

Best,

Comment: I have updated both of them, Chrome is at v58 and Chromedriver at 29

Comment: You need to update selenium jar too. Have you done that?